Obtaining telegram user id through phone number
A long time ago, you could fetch telegram users id through their phone number, but now they changed it and youll need to add them to your contacts first or you cant fetch it.
This is a problem, as im working with a massive list of phone numbers and my task is to automate the thing and retrieve the user ids of existing telegram accounts.
Is there any other way to get user id using a phone number?
A telegram "mod" called Nicegram allows you to see anyones user id instantly in their profiles, how can it get their id?
I tried using telethon, pyrogram and telegram-python-bot.
Tried making that they add the phone number to the contacts before fetching the id but it will give flood issues when adding more than 50 contacts.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
